# Trying to attached jpeg file on ASP.NET Mail Code

Tags: asp.net, web

Hello all i got a mail code like this

```
body = "Dear " & cName & "," & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Your request for the " & vehHeader & " (" & FormatCurrency(vehPrice)& ")" & " has been received and will be reviewed promptly." & vbcrlf & "We will contact you shortly to verify your information." & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & "Thank you for using website"
AppSendMail AppSupportMailto, cEMail, "Confirmation of request...", body
AppReportError "CUBid.asp: Error sending confirmation e-mail."
```

so this sends an auto response to the customer but this just plain text would i be able to add a photo as an attacthment or is this ASP.NET code is to old?
please let me know if you dont understand the code.

Comment: That depends on what library you are using to send your mail...

Comment: Hi, you may want to edit your question title if possible to correct the "APS.NET" to ASP.NET. Some people may miss your question if searching.

Comment: Would i be able to ad an HTML Image on this line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of `AppSendMail`. Are you using a custom mail library?

If you use the standard .NET mail API (System.Net.Mail), you can easily add attachments and use Html format for the body in order to use rich text.

Here's a sample of attaching a file to an email using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx

Comment: Would it be easier to send the photo as and html?

Comment: If you have a place to host the images then it may be easier to go that route, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're best bet would be to ensure your body was HTML and then just include an

```
<img src ="http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourimage.jpg" />
```

tag in it and link to an image thats located on your website.  This way the size of the email is still small and you can format your email as you please.